# ipython doesn't update figure while rerun the script on Mac

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I haven't been able to find an answer to my question using google, so I will make a new post here.

I'm using matplotlib with ipython. I'll use a simple script (called a.py) to demonstrate my question.

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(2*x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I can run this script within ipython (started with "ipython --pylab") using the command "run a.py". It will create a figure window with the right plot. However, if I modify the code; let's say changing y to np.sin(x), and save the script.  If I run the script again by calling "run a.py", the figure window doesn't change. No new lines will be added to the figure. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?  I'm new to Python/Ipython/matplotlib.

I'm using Mac OS Yosemite, Python34, py34-ipython, py34-matplotlib.  Thanks a log.

---- Update -----

If I use 
    plt.savefig("c.pdf")
instead of 
    plt.show()

The ipython and the %run command works the way I think it should be; i.e., if I update the script, and %run a.py again, the changes into the script should be reflected in the figure.

--------- More Update --------

One solution I've found is to use command "plt.close()" before any plotting.

Answer (score 1):

The [`%run`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) magic is used to run complete scripts in `ipython`. That's not exactly what you are trying to do. You may want to have a look at the [`%load`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-load) magic

In contrast to `%run` which runs scripts, `%load` can be used to pull code into your current `ipython` session.

- use `%load a.py`
- do your modifications and save file `a.py`
- reuse `%load a.py`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, however,  and it doesn't work the way I think it should.  I just need to re-run the script with some modifications. I think I could do what I want before I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: @Bill If that's not what you are trying to do, then I didn't get following part of your question: `the figure window doesn't change. No new lines will be added to the figure.` I assumed that you want a sinus and a cosine function in the same plot. Was it a misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do.  But see my update to the original post. I think maybe it's a problem of the backend. I'm using MacOSX backend.